# App crashes when Backendless method persistenceService is called

Tags: ios, swift, crash, backendless

I am making an app that uses Backendless for holding data. I have everything hooked up as they said to [here](https://backendless.com/mobile-developers/quick-start-guide-for-ios/).

However, the app crashes when the `persistenceService` method is called:

```
backendless.persistenceService.of(UserSchema.ofClass()).save(user)
```

Here is the code for the file:

```
import UIKit

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var userName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateOfBirth: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var zip: UITextField!

    let backendless = Backendless.sharedInstance()
    // Create a new instance of UserSchema for the use of createing a new user.
    let user = UserSchema()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func signUp() {

        // Check to make sure all fields have proper values and are not nill.
        if userName.text != nil && email.text != nil && password.text != nil && firstName.text != nil
            && lastName.text != nil && dateOfBirth != nil && zip.text != nil && Int(zip.text!) != nil {

                // Asign text from fields to the variables for the new user.
                user.userName = userName.text
                user.email = email.text
                user.password = password.text
                user.firstName = firstName.text
                user.lastName = lastName.text
                user.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth.text
                user.zip = zip.text

                backendless.persistenceService.of(UserSchema.ofClass()).save(user)

                shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier("succesfulSignUp", sender: nil)

        } else {
            // Alert the user if any of the values are nil so they can fix the issue.
            let emptyTextFieldAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Empty Field", message: "Please make sure all fields have proper values", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            emptyTextFieldAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { action -> Void in
                // Do nothing
            }))
            self.presentViewController(emptyTextFieldAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `UserSchema` class:

```
import Foundation

// Class for data that gets sent to the Backendless database

class UserSchema: NSObject {

    var zip: String?
    var userName: String?
    var password: String?
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
    var email: String?
    var dateOfBirth: String?
}
```

What causes the crash?

Here is a screen shot of the schema:

[image]

This is a repo so you can clone and test the code. I have made a couple changes that are different from the code here in the question:

https://github.com/calebkleveter/chatter

To reproduce the crash; run the app, select the sign up button on the sign in page, fill in all the fields with proper information, then tap the "Sign Up!" button. The app will crash.

**Update:**

I managed to get a log output by placing a brake point at this line

```
backendless.persistenceService.of(UserSchema.ofClass()).save(user)
```

And stepping into it, I then stepped through the app untill it crashed and I got this:

```
2016-04-11 12:04:09.025 Chatter[21686:11538370] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106c64e65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001090f5deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106b23652 -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 290
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106b807e4 +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:] + 52
    4   Chatter                             0x00000001053ffc53 -[PersistenceService save:] + 409
    5   Chatter                             0x00000001052e2eb5 _TFC7Chatter20SignUpViewController6signUpfS0_FT_T_ + 8709
    6   Chatter                             0x00000001052e3452 _TToFC7Chatter20SignUpViewController6signUpfS0_FT_T_ + 34
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000107bd3194 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000107d426fc -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000107d429c8 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 311
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000107d41af8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000107c4249b -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000107c431d0 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000107bf1b66 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000107bcbd97 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6844
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106b90a31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106b8695c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106b85e13 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106b85828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010b743ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000107bd1610 UIApplicationMain + 171
    21  Chatter                             0x00000001052ea13d main + 109
    22  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000109c4692d start + 1
    23  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: So your problem is solved now?

Comment: @Scadge, no that did not solve the crash. It solved the output I was getting. I added a link in my question to a GitHub repo I made for it.

Comment: Do you receive any log? Seems that you have a lot of constraints in your project and some of them are conflicting.
Anyway, this doesn't seem to be related to Backendless.

Comment: @Scadge I don't get any output in the console other then `(lldb) `. Here is a screen shot of what Xcode looks like after the crash: [Screen shot of Xcode](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8tUul.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I accidentally gave the `APP_ID` and `SECRET_KEY` variables the same value. After fixing that everything is working fine!